# Tooltip causes bootstrap3 nav list-items to bounce on hover

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I added tooltips to the `<li>` elements of my boostrap navbar and noticed that the list-items bounce when the tooltip shows.  I would like to have tooltips on a bootstrap menu without the bounce.

Example Code:

```js
/* Latest compiled and minified JavaScript included as External Resource */
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
<p>
Hover over menu items to activate tooltip. </p><p>

The 2px margin-top is removed from li+li styling when tooltip div is appended to dom.  
</p>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default hidden-print">
<div id="navbartemplate" class="collapse navbar-collapse">

        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked nav-custom">

  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Your mailing address on file"><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The css for li+li adds a margin-top of 2px to the bottom li.  When the tooltip is apppended to the dom, beneath the item that activates it, it removes the margin.  To fix this, add the tooltip to the anchor tag.

Example Code of Fix:

```js
/* Latest compiled and minified JavaScript included as External Resource */
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 
<nav class="navbar navbar-default hidden-print">
<div id="navbartemplate" class="collapse navbar-collapse">

        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked nav-custom">

  <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li ><a href="#news"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Your mailing address on file">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</nav>
</div>
```